# How do I allow tenants in my shop?

Tags: pocket-clothier

I cracked the top 900 for my clothing shop, which gave me the ability to have a Dumpling Stand in my shop.

Problem is, when I try to build it (or any other tenant) in my shop, I get told there isn't enough room.

How do I make sure that there is enough room to build these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenants are a strange name for them.  Each floor has a different number of spaces for shelves (which can also hold fixtures), and tenants.  Tenants can only be placed on the larger tiles, that appear when you choose to install something.

At the beginning, your main floor cannot hold *any* tenants.  You do, however, have a second floor.  This floor can hold two tenants.